# Error: Failed to execut 'removeChild' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm new to JavaScript and programming in general.  I've put together my first browser game and while everything functions, I keep getting this pesky error in the console from my hover function that says:

> "NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node"

```
function hover(myid) {
var id = myid;
var index = id[5];
document.getElementById(id).removeChild(GAME.mound[index]);
document.getElementById(id).appendChild(GAME.hover[index]);
GAME.sound[0].play();
}
```

Both `GAME.mound` and `GAME.hover` are arrays that store images. The thing I can't figure out is that I have a function that is nearly identical to reverse the image switch caused by the hover function, but it doesn't throw the error.

```
function out(myid) {
var id = myid;
var index = id[5];
document.getElementById(id).removeChild(GAME.hover[index]);
document.getElementById(id).appendChild(GAME.mound[index]);
}
```

Here is a line from the HTML that calls the functions:

```
<div id="drift0" class="snowdrift" onmouseover = "hover(this.id)" onmouseout = "out(this.id)" onclick = "popup(this.id)"></div>
```

Any help in this is greatly appreciated.  Let me know if I didn't provide all the information needed to answer the question.

Comment: Aside from this code not showing any insertion point for that "Node", you say it's an array of images - assuming that you actually convert it to a DOM Node somewhere, an array of images is actually a NodeList and can't be handled all at once just with `removeChild`.  I would suggest iterating over it with a `for` loop and use `replaceChild(newChild, oldChild)` instead of what you're currently using to remove then append.

Comment: @Deryck—HTMLCollections bear only the feintest resemblance to arrays, but suggesting *replaceChild* is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to handle this exception, so do that. There doesn't seem to be any point to copying *myid*, it's a string and even if you modify it, the original isn't changed. You should pass a reference to the element to the listener rather than the ID, as it saves using *getElementById* twice.

Also, as Deryck suggested, [*replaceChild*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-785887307) will do the change in one step:

```
function hover(myid) {
  var el = document.getElementById(myid);
  var index = myid[5];

  if (GAME.mound[index].parentNode === el) {
    // Replace mound image with hover image
    e.replaceChild(GAME.hover[index], GAME.mound[index]);
  }
  GAME.sound[0].play();
}
```

If you pass *this* to the function rather than *this.id*, you could do:

```
function hover(el) {
  var index = el.id[5];

  if (GAME.mound[index].parentNode === el) {
    e.replaceChild(GAME.hover[index], GAME.mound[index]);
  }
  GAME.sound[0].play();
}
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks so much.  I passed this to the function as opposed to this.id.  I'm not understanding the difference between nodes and elements.  Any resources you would recommend that might help me get a better handle on how nodes work?

Comment: A [*Node*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247) is a basic entity in the DOM (documents are a tree of nodes). There are 12 types, one of which is [*Element*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-745549614). The DOM Core is designed to work with any type of document, HTML and XML are the most common.

Comment: Thanks for the link RobG.  Reading now to see if I can get a better handle on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

If hover is called twice without an out in between you will get this problem. The exception will cause the callback to exit - which will not cause a problem since the appendChild was called the time before. I don't remember the exact edge cases but I did look at this a while ago. I suggest you keep a flag to ensure that they only execute as a toggle.

It is not fatal if you don't do anything, although I don't know what the performance disadvantages are. The easiest if not prettiest solution is to wrap it in a try catch:

```
try {
  document.getElementById(id).removeChild(GAME.mound[index]);
  document.getElementById(id).appendChild(GAME.hover[index]);
} catch(e) {}
```

It would be better to look at your code and see what the issue is and/or find a work-around that stops the exception occurring.
      GAME.sound[0].play();

Comment: *try..catch* should only be used as a last resort if there is no other way of detecting or avoiding the error. It's much more efficient to first check that *GAME.mound[index]* is a child of the element before trying to remove it.

Comment: agreed, as I noted in the last paragraph. It requires more information on the code-base to implement the correct solution.